# Still ng2-bootstrap shows 404 (Not Found) in Angular 2

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap

Have tried different approaches. still have error with

GET http://localhost:8080/node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/bundles/ng2-bootstrap.min.js 404 (Not Found)

Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:8080/node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap.js(…)

this is my index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Angular 2 TypeScript Gulp QuickStart</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
<script src="lib/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="lib/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="lib/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<!--ng2-bootstrap-->
<script src="../node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/bundles/ng2-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
<!--ng-bootstrap-->
<!--<script src="node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/bundles/ng2-bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->
<script>
    System.import('app')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
</head>
<!-- 3. Display the application -->
<body>
<my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

here is systemjs.config.js:

```
(function (global) {

// map tells the System loader where to look for things
var map = {
    'app': 'app', // 'dist',
    'rxjs': 'lib/rxjs',
    '@angular': 'lib/@angular',
    'ng2-bootstrap': 'node_modules/ng2-bootstrap',
     moment: 'node_modules/moment/moment.js'
};

// packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
var packages = {
    'app': {main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js'},
    'rxjs': {defaultExtension: 'js'},
    'ng2-bootstrap': {defaultJSExtensions: true}
};

var packageNames = [
    '@angular/common',
    '@angular/compiler',
    '@angular/core',
    '@angular/http',
    '@angular/platform-browser',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
    '@angular/router',
    '@angular/router-deprecated',
    '@angular/testing',
    '@angular/upgrade'
];

// add package entries for angular packages in the form '@angular/common': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
packageNames.forEach(function (pkgName) {
    packages[pkgName] = {main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js'};
});

var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
};

// filterSystemConfig - index.html's chance to modify config before we register it.
if (global.filterSystemConfig) {
    global.filterSystemConfig(config);
}

System.config(config);

})(this);
```

here is
part of app.component.ts:

```
//datepicker
import {DATEPICKER_DIRECTIVES} from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
```

Comment: I found an issue: I've moved 'moment' and 'ng2-bootstrap/components" folders and ng2-bootstrap.js into build/lib folder. So now at least I don't get errorrs ans see datepicker.

Comment: The links are broken

Comment: Just a note that ng2-bs was renamed to ngx-bootstrap

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always refer to https://github.com/valor-software/angular2-quickstart to check sample system.js config

Answer (score 1):

1. Open **systemjs.config.js** file
2. Add this '**ng2-bootstrap': 'node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/bundles/ng2-bootstrap.umd.js',** in the **map** object

3.adding this **import { DatepickerModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap';** to my **app.module.ts** file fixed my problem, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Open

> systemjs.config.js

add this path :

> '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap': 'npm:@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js'

in **map object**

Comment: It works only after changing it to '@ng-bootstrap': 'npm:@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js' for me

Comment: question was about ngx-bootstrap ;)